# Smarty print comment gives wrong values in multi dimensional array

Tags: php, smarty

We have a social network startup and we need to integrate smarty templates. I have a php array namely `$profile_tasks` . An element in `$profile_tasks` have the following properties ;

```
    [0] => Array
    (
        [name] => hello
        [location] => 
        [date] => 
        [time3] => 0
        [time1] => 
        [state] => 0
        [like_count] => 0
        [comment_count] => 2
        [does_id] => 91
        [comments] => Array
            (
                [sender_id] => 27
                [content] => khhkhjkkhk
                [time] => 2012-02-09 20:06:13
                [user_name] => aacanakin
                [picture_url] => http://graph.facebook.com/fb_user_name/picture
            )

    )
```

In my smarty template file, I have assigned the `$profile_tasks` array like this ;

```
$smarty->assign("profile_tasks", $profile_tasks);
```

In my .tpl file, there is no problem in printing any of the attributes like `[name]` or `[location]` fields. I have the following code for name printing ;

```
  {foreach name=outer item=profile_task from=$profile_tasks}  

    {$profile_task.name}
    {$profile_task.locatin} // these two works correctly

    {foreach name=inner item=comment from=$profile_task.comments}

      {comment.user_name} // these three statements doesn't return correct values
      {comment.picture_url}
      {comment.content}

    {/foreach}  

   {/foreach}
```

So, as I stated before, the values inside `comments` array are not correct. What should I change in the inner loop ? Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use

```
  {comments.user_name} // these three statements doesn't return correct values
  {comments.picture_url}
  {comments.content}
```

you dont need

```
  {foreach name=inner item=comment from=$profile_task.comments}
```

if your comments array had multiple sub arrays then you would.

UPDATE:
Update based on comment.  Your array needs to look like this for your origional code to work

```
    [comments] => Array(
    [0] =>  Array
        (
            [sender_id] => 27
            [content] => khhkhjkkhk
            [time] => 2012-02-09 20:06:13
            [user_name] => aacanakin
            [picture_url] => http://graph.facebook.com/fb_user_name/picture
        )
   )
```

PS.  On a subnote, I very early on realised that using the default `{}` to denote smarty tags is really annoying as you cannot happily co-exist with javascript on a html template page.  If you havn't gone too far down the route I would use

```
$left_delimiter -> '{[';
$right_delimiter -> ']}';
```

to specify an alternative.  This means you dont have to worry about using the {literal} tags anywhere.

Comment: comments have multiple values. this is why I need inner foreach

Comment: comments dont have multiple values in your array.  Correct your array and your code will work.

Comment: profile_tasks array can have multiple comments. this example just doesn't contain multiple comments. I'll edit the post.

Comment: @arascanakin, its very difficult to answer a question that isnt the one you asked ! :)

Comment: Ok. I just realized that the comment array doesn't work correctly. let me fix the other problem. Thank you for the answers :-)